# Rebuild yum repo

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, yum

We have a private repo on Amazon S3. I didn't setup so I don't know how it was done. Now I need to add some new packages to it but they aren't being recognized. I'm assuming it is because the repo keep the list of files in the repodata folder. How do I rebuild that?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `createrepo` command to build and/or update the repository metadata.